# How can I customise a Flutter app after releasing

Tags: flutter

I would like to know whether there is anyway I can customise a Flutter app for some people who has taken it from an app store.

Ex.
I have released my app to Play store and 5 people have downloaded it. 3 of them need changes to the app but not the other 2. Changes may like:

1. The way a calculation is done
2. The database field size might need to increase
3. A new field might need to be added to a screen

Is there anyway I can achieve these without releasing a separate app for those 3 customers.

Comment: If the change is user specific you could probably use some like Firebase's Remote Config. Or conditionally render your UI based on user information

Comment: Considering you probably know about the general power of `if` statements, can you explain a little where you see the problems? It is possible easily, but on the other hand one could probably write whole books about things easily possible. Can you specify your question a little bit? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks guys. Its not easy as a set if if-then-else- or switch-case setup. Target customers of my app is different companies (say 50 different companies). I develop a core-standard functionality but they will need slightly different versions of it in different places (as mention above). I don't want to branch out my code per customer requirement as it will not be scalable in long run. I have to support the app for 5 years at least. ... I will check on the Remote Config .. Thanks for that,